# Bootstrap collapse classic navigation menu and expand to modal fullscreen

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, navigationbar

I'm struggling to create a navbar menu that is standard on big screen,
like this one: [bootstrap collapse navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h) and which collapses on a small screen with a hamburger menu. Then I want the hamburger menu to expand the menu onclick with a fullscreen modal, [this way :`%button.btn.navbar-btn.btn-link.pull-right{"data-target" => "#modalNavigation", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button"}`](https://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/EKoNrO)

The problem is that I want the data toggle to be `"data-toggle" => "modal"` on small screen and `data-toggle="collapse"` on big screen.

What can I do to have a collapsible menu **and** fullscreen modal menu on the same navbar using bootstrap?

Comment: You’d have 2 buttons and show hide them depending on screen size using css media queries (responsive design).. The hamburger one would lunch modal pop up and the regular one would launch non modal (if I understood you)..